# Generate random number with a certain prefix what am i doing wrong

Tags: php

I've been playing about with the uniqid but it started giving me the 13 long string.

I'm looking for a prefix of 100 with up to 6 random numbers afterwards

thanks any help appreciated

```
function generate_order(){

    $order_ref="";
    $a=uniqid(prefix,100);  
    $num4=array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
    $num=rand(0,9);
    $num2=rand(0,9);
    $num3=rand(0,9);
    shuffle($num4);
    //now the final
    $order_ref = $num4[0].$num4[3].$num.$num4[1].$num2.$num4[2].$num3.$num4[4];
}
```

Comment: How do you use $a ?

Comment: It's a change and hope for the best scenario lol at the min it works ok without wanting a prefix but would be nice to someone be able to change the prefix to whatever I want.

Comment: What's best way to get the number to start with 100 as the prefix for example 10043672, 100473633 the digits after the 100 are random

Comment: 100000000+rand(1,100000)

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the function here, `uniqid()` is not used for randomness, it is used for uniqueness. To quote from the manual _"Gets a prefixed unique identifier based on the current time in microseconds."_. Unless you create two id's at the same time, it's pretty hard to get the same result from `uniqid()`

Comment: Your code for the random number is equivalent to `$order_ref = sprintf('%08d', mt_rand(0, 99999999));`

Comment: `prefix` where did you define that constant? you better go RTM https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php - you should be getting an error here.

Answer (score 1):

I've got some remakrs to the code above:

1. Why are you doing a `shuffle()` on an array with numbers ranging from 1 to 9? This is the same as doing `rand(1,9)`
2. Taking point one into account, using `rand(10000000, 99999999)` will give you the same result.
3. `$a=uniqid(prefix,100)` is not used in your function
4. The prefix in `uniqid()` should be a string.
5. Your function doesn't `return`. You should use `return $order_ref;`

Hope these will help you fix your function.

#### In response to your comment

```
$order_ref = '100'.rand(100000, 999999);
```

#### Additional suggestions

If you are planning to use this as an order reference as I suspect, I do not recommand just using random numbers. This will give you a big chance of having duplicate numbers.

Instead, I suggest using `$order_ref = '100'.date('u').rand(10, 99);`. This will give you a random number based on the current time and thus prevent (or at least minimize) the chance of duplicate order references.

Comment: The $a=uniqid(prefix,100); was me trying to accomplish the 100 prefix from browsing the net.

all I want is a prefix of 100 and 6 random numbers afterwards.

Thanks for the helps guys il have a play about with it now

Comment: @Arsenoll Take a look at my edited answer. If I understand you correctly, thats all you need.

Comment: @Arsenoll If you are satisfied with my answer, you can accept it by clicking on the button to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 100 before your result, then use the prefix to enter your desired string

Using `uniqid(100)` should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do
1. Define your prefix
2. Generate random number
3. Concat both

```
$prefix="some_prefix";
$rand_no = rand(1,100);
$rand_no_with_prefix = $prefix.$rand_no;
```

You can Google for exact syntax and functions.
This is just basic logic I would follow.
Hope it helps. 
Also step 4 would be to parse if required(if concated random number needs to be integer)